# Probability Proofs

Tags: probability, logic

I had a question that I needed some help on:

> a) If $P(A) = P(B) = P(AB)$, then $P(A\neg B+B\neg A) = 0$
>
> > b) If $P(A) = P(B) = 1$, then $P(AB) = 1$

For the first one, I started down the track where we can solve $P(AB) = P(A\mid B)P(B)$, however, I realized that when we apply it to the problem, we get $P(A\neg B) = P(A\mid \neg B)P(\neg B)$, which we can't use because we don't know $\neg B$. I seemed to be stumped on where to go.

On the second problem, I can simply use logic based on the axioms of probability to say that if the probability of something (take $P(A)$), such that $P(A) = 1$, then $P(A) = S$, for S being the sample space. Thus, if $P(B) = P(A)$ then $P(B) = S$ as well and their intersection is thus S and equal to 1. However, I'm not sure if there is a more mathematical way to show this?

Thanks so much in advanced for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Be careful with your writing ! Do you mean $A\cap B$ for $AB$ and $A\cap B^c$ for $A\neg B$ ? If yes, what is the sense of $A+B$ if $A$ and $B$ are sets ? Is it the union ?

Comment: What means $A+B$?

Comment: @Masacroso Billy is using Boolean algebra for connectives between events instead of the standard set algebra convention.  So $A+B$ is more usually written $A\cup B$.  Likewise $AB$ is $A\cap B$, and $\neg B$ is $B^\complement$.

Comment: Graham has it correct. I wasn't sure how to write the caps in syntax and I knew they were logical equivalents. That is "OR" = '+' and "AND" = " * ". That can usually work for probability, but especially for set based stuff like this I guess it is better to use the other.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one

$$\begin{align}P(A) & =  P((A\cap B) \cup (A\cap \bar{B})) \\ & = P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap \bar{B}) \\ & = P(A) + P(A\cap \bar{B}) \\ & \implies P(A\cap \bar{B})=0.\end{align}$$

Similarly, $P(\bar{A}\cap B)=0.$ Finally

$$P((A\cap \bar{B})\cup (\bar{A}\cap B))=P(A\cap \bar{B})+ P(\bar{A}\cap B)=0.$$

For the second one

$$1\ge P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=2-P(A\cap B)\implies P(A\cap B)\ge 1,$$ from where $P(A\cap B)=1. $

Comment: What is the reason for the downvote?

Comment: I didn't down vote, very helpful!
One question, could you explain a little bit for my understanding how $P(A) + P(A\cap \bar{B}) \implies P(A\cap \bar{B})=0$? From the information provided, how do we determine both are 0?

Comment: Note that you have $P(A)=P(A)+P(A\cap \bar{B}).$ So, if you substract $P(A)$ in both sides of the equality you get that $P(A\cap\bar{B})=0$.

Comment: Ah, I completely forgot that, that make much more sense! Do you do that same kind of math in the second part where you subtract 2 from $P(A \cap B)$?

Comment: More or less. We have $1\ge 2-P(A\cap B).$ Rearranging terms we get $P(A\cap B)\ge 2-1=1,$ from where the conclusion follows.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I downvoted ! Of course your answer is a correct answer. I downvoted because I think that your answer is nonteaching in the way that there is nothing complicate here and a simple application of formulas I gave is more than enough to solve this problem. So I don't downvoted the mathematic of your answer but  the nonteaching of your answer.

Comment: @Surb Ok. It is a reason. I agree in some sense with you. But if you look at the comments above, your adequate hint could be enough. Anyway, thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B),\quad P(A\cup B)\geq P(A) \quad \text{and}\quad P(A\cup B)\geq P(B).$$

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I understand that property exists, but I don't see how that helps.

Comment: @BillyThorton: First, edit your original post ! Then, I will not make your work ! What you ask are just very simple consequence of the Hint I gave you. Think why !